# Shiro Annotation not working with Spring Boot 2.0.4 with Jersey REST and JDBC Realm

Tags: apache, spring-boot, jersey-2.0, shiro

I am trying to integrate Apache Shiro in my Spring Boot (2.0.4) application with JDBC realm and Jersey REST using Shiro Annotations for permission check. However only authentication part is working and authorization is NOT called by shiro on annotation.

My Shiro Configuration is as follows:

```
@Bean(name = "realm")
@DependsOn("lifecycleBeanPostProcessor")
public JdbcRealm jdbcRealm() {
    MyJDBCRealm realm = new MyJDBCRealm();
    Sha256CredentialsMatcher credentialsMatcher = new Sha256CredentialsMatcher();
    credentialsMatcher.setStoredCredentialsHexEncoded(false);
    credentialsMatcher.setHashIterations(1024);
    realm.setCredentialsMatcher(credentialsMatcher);
    realm.setAuthenticationQuery("SELECT password, salt FROM User WHERE email = ?");
    realm.setPermissionsLookupEnabled(true);
    realm.setUserRolesQuery("select roleName from UserRole where email = ?");
    realm.setPermissionsQuery("select permission from RolesPermission where roleName = ?");
    realm.init();
    return realm;
}

@Bean(name = "securityManager")
public DefaultWebSecurityManager securityManager() {
    DefaultWebSecurityManager securityManager = new DefaultWebSecurityManager();
    securityManager.setRealm(jdbcRealm());
    return securityManager;
}

@Bean
public ShiroFilterChainDefinition shiroFilterChainDefinition() {
    DefaultShiroFilterChainDefinition chainDefinition = new DefaultShiroFilterChainDefinition();
    // use permissive to NOT require authentication, our controller Annotations will decide that
    //chainDefinition.addPathDefinition("/**", "authcBasic[permissive]");
    chainDefinition.addPathDefinition("/**", "authcBasic");
    return chainDefinition;
}

@Bean(name = "shiroFilter")
public AbstractShiroFilter shiroFilter() throws Exception {
    ShiroFilterFactoryBean shiroFilter = new ShiroFilterFactoryBean();
    shiroFilter.setSecurityManager(securityManager());
    Map<String, String> filterChainDefinitionMapping = new HashMap<>();
    filterChainDefinitionMapping.put("/**", "authcBasic");
    shiroFilter.setFilterChainDefinitionMap(filterChainDefinitionMapping);
    Map<String, Filter> filters = new HashMap<>();
    filters.put("anon", new AnonymousFilter());
    filters.put("authcBasic", new BasicHttpAuthenticationFilter());
    filters.put("authcBasicRoles", new RolesAuthorizationFilter());
    filters.put("authcBasicPermissions", new PermissionsAuthorizationFilter());
    shiroFilter.setFilters(filters);
    return (AbstractShiroFilter) shiroFilter.getObject();
}

@Bean (name = "lifecycleBeanPostProcessor")
public static LifecycleBeanPostProcessor lifecycleBeanPostProcessor() {

    return new LifecycleBeanPostProcessor();
}

@Bean
@ConditionalOnMissingBean
public AuthorizationAttributeSourceAdvisor getAuthorizationAttributeSourceAdvisor(DefaultSecurityManager securityManager) {
    // This is to enable Shiro's security annotations
    AuthorizationAttributeSourceAdvisor sourceAdvisor = new AuthorizationAttributeSourceAdvisor();
    sourceAdvisor.setSecurityManager(securityManager);
    return sourceAdvisor;
}

@ConditionalOnMissingBean
@Bean(name = "defaultAdvisorAutoProxyCreator")
@DependsOn("lifecycleBeanPostProcessor")
public DefaultAdvisorAutoProxyCreator defaultAdvisorAutoProxyCreator() {
    DefaultAdvisorAutoProxyCreator proxyCreator = new DefaultAdvisorAutoProxyCreator();
    proxyCreator.setProxyTargetClass(true);
    return proxyCreator;
}


@Bean
public CacheManager cacheManager() {
    // Caching isn't needed in this example, but we will use the MemoryConstrainedCacheManager for this example.
    return new MemoryConstrainedCacheManager();
}
```

With the above code Shiro does the authentication but it comes to Jersey REST controller it does not invoke authorization on Shiro Annotation

```
@POST
@Path("/authorize/")
@Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
@Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
@RequiresPermissions("service:create")
public Session register(UserInfo inputData) throws AppException{.......
```

If someone can let me know what I am missing to get this working would be very helpful.

As requested adding code for MyJDBCRealm.

@Component
public class MyJDBCRealm extends JdbcRealm {

```
@Autowired
UserManagerDAO userManagerDAO;
@Override
protected AuthenticationInfo doGetAuthenticationInfo(AuthenticationToken token) throws AuthenticationException {
    // identify account to log to
    UsernamePasswordToken userPassToken = (UsernamePasswordToken) token;
    final String username = userPassToken.getUsername();

    if (username == null) {
        System.out.println("Username is null.");
        return null;
    }

    // read password hash and salt from db
    final User user = userManagerDAO.getUserByEmail(username);

    if (user == null) {
        System.out.println("No account found for user [" + username + "]");
        return null;
    }

    // return salted credentials
    SaltedAuthenticationInfo info = new MySaltedAuthentication(username, user.getPassword(), user.getSalt());

    return info;
}
```

}

I am also providing you the shiro pom dependency I used in this Spring boot 2.0.4 application. Please note that Spring boot version used is 2.0.4 which uses Jersey 2.26 version. Somewhere I read that 2.26 jersey version does not work with shiro annotation due to some injection implementation issue. However if I downgrade jersey to 2.25 some spring bean injections stops working and server crashes on startup.

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.shiro</groupId>
        <artifactId>shiro-spring-boot-web-starter</artifactId>
        <version>1.4.0-RC2</version>
    </dependency>
```

Comment: add **static** in the method of public static DefaultAdvisorAutoProxyCreator defaultAdvisorAutoProxyCreator

Comment: Tried this, but still Shiro is not invoking Authorization flow on annotation.

Comment: can you paste the code of MyJDBCRealm

Comment: I have added the code, please have a look

Comment: why add **@Component** on the MyJDBCRealm?

Comment: because I am using AutoWire annotation to inject my other class UserManagerDAO. I think this would not cause any issue with Shiro Authorization invocation as this part is only triggered during Authentication which is working fine. Trouble is with Shiro Annotations which is not invoking Authorization workflow at all.